# Calculate effective diffusion coefficient

Tags: matlab, statistics, stochastic-process, probability-distribution

I need to compute the drift velocity 
( v=d/dt[r(t)] ) and the effective diffusion coefficient 
(Deff=d/dt[r(t)^2]-d/dt[r(t)]^2 ) from random trajectories for the case of Brownian motion over a periodic potential.

As a mere example assume I have an ensemble of random trajectories:

```
dt=1e-2; N=1e6; Ensemble=200; Do=1;
wn=sqrt(2*Do*dt)*normrnd(0,1,[Ensemble,N]);
time=0:dt:N*dt;
```

I first compute the drift velocity:

```
 P2 = polyfit(time,mean(wn(:,:)-wn(:,1)),1);
vx_Sim=P2(1);
```

which gives me the expected value of the analytic solution.
Then I compute the effective diffusion like:

```
XM=mean((wn(:,:)-wn(:,1)).^2,1)/(2*Do);
P =polyfit(time,sqrt(XM),1); 
DDeffSim=P(1);
```

yet I don't get back the expected result from the analytic solutions for the particular Brownian motion I'm studying. Am I calculating this wrong?

Comment: We cannot reproduce your problem because Do is not defined.

Comment: sorry, I have updated the examples with the value of Do

Comment: `time` has not the right size; change it to `time=1:dt:N*dt` for example.

Comment: I run the code, I get `vx_Sim=-8.2e-10` and `DDeffSim=-9.1e-10`. Seems to me the same result, taking into account numerical approximations. So what is the problem?

Comment: so theoretically vx=0 which is right compared to the simulations, but DDeff should equal 1.

Comment: So your error lies in the computation of `XM`, check with the original formula. As I said, I can't help you more because I dont know anything about this subject.

Answer (score 0):

so the effective diffusion coefficient is related to the variance of my ensemble of vectors, so I used the Matlab function var() to compute the diffusion.

```
DDeffsim=mean(var(wn).')'./(2*dt)/NT;
```